# Rails: Best way to query across multiple models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have got a simple rails app, with three models, and what I am trying to do is query across the different models.

My app models are as follows:

```
user.rb:
    has_many :forms
    has_one :user_info

user_info.rb
    attr_accessible :state

form.rb:
    attr_accessible :status
    belongs_to :user
```

What i am trying to do, is to see how many users have a certain status, and who live in a specific state. Essentially, I am trying to do the something like this:
    .where("status = ? AND state = ?", "open", "AZ")

Is there a rails way to do this sort of query?
Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the other tables to the `User` table and then use them in a `where` clause:

```
User.joins(:user_info, :forms).where(user_infos: {state: "open"}, forms: {state: "AZ"})
```

Comment: that worked like a charm. The one thing that threw me off when I first tried it though, was while I could query on the forms part, querying on the user_info would fail. Turns out in the where clause, I had to use the plural version of the model, i.e. user_infos, though I am not sure why that would be the case?

Comment: If you look at the SQL this generates (you can add `to_sql` onto the end to see the output without running the query), the raw SQL uses the plural names, so I guess the where clause is really just concatenating stuff together (`tables.hash_key = hash_value`) so it needs you to supply the SQLy name and not the table name.

Answer (score 2):

I recently made a gem for this exact purpose:

[activerecord_where_assoc](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc)

With it, it would look like:

```
User.where_assoc_exists(:user_info, state: "open")
    .where_assoc_exists(:forms, state: "AZ")
```

It solves a lot of potential problems that can arrise when doing it with joins. I made a whole page dedicated to those problems: [Alternatives problems](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/ALTERNATIVES_PROBLEMS.md)